# How many timers can I create in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, timer, arduino

I am working with a table (struct) that stores entries of received messages. I need to monitor a specific operation for each entry periodically, which is why I thought of creating a timer for each created entry to monitor how long this entry has been in the table, and based on the duration, I need to execute some commands and restart the timer.

I am new to timers and callbacks in C, but I know that each timer leads to a new thread. My questions is, how many timers can I create on a standard board?

I know a different method would be to add a new member for the timer operation and iterate over the table for this to work in non-critical events with one timer, but I am trying to avoid this as the table entries can affect the whole program. If it is not possible to create many timers (+1000), what would be the other ideal way of doing this?

Comment: The C language doesn't know about timers. You forgot to mention your platform.

Comment: In C? None, no timers at all. There are no "timers" in the C language or standard library. You have to tell us the environment you're in, the operating system, and how you create the "timers".

Comment: Someprogrammerdude & Jabberwocky, thanks for reminding me! I am working on windows os. I have updated the question too.

Comment: You still haven't told us what "timers" you are using. Are you using the Windows API [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions? Some *other* time functions? And *why* do you need so many timers? Are you sure you need timers at all, and not only a timestamp that you compare to the current time when you need it (which is the usual way to keep track of how long ago something happened).

Comment: Some other time functions I believe since I am not using `SetTimer`. Where I can find which one is the one I am using? 
The timestamp is the field that I will have to include in the table, which already has a member for expiration date for entry expiration. This other timestamp would be for an external operation. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @ryyker I meant for a board like Arduino for example, but the development is happening on windows. If this is also platform dependent then I guess I will have to fix my question further.

Comment: Ok this is just complete nonsense... you cannot develop a threaded Windows application and port it to a bloody hobbyist Arduino. Because... the Arduino is not a PC! It is some 100 times lower level than a Windows program.

Comment: 1000+ timers? An Arduino Uno has only 2kiB of memory. The only thing you will get 1000+ of, are single bytes. There is no way to store 1000+ messages. And Arduino is C++ not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries in the table should be "expired" (and removed) at certain times, then here is a possible solution, using only a *single* timer:

First of all use a *priority queue* where the "priority" is the expiration time. You can of course use any other table-like structure, but keep it sorted on the expiration time (it simplify things later).

Then have your single recurring timer, which is triggered ten, twenty or maybe more times per second.

When the timer is triggered, you get the current time, and simply remove all elements in the table whose expiration time have passed (comparing its expiration time with the current time). If the table is sorted on expiration date, it's a very simple loop where you compare the time from the "top" element, and if expired then "pop" the top element.

You can use the same or similar techniques for just about *any* timing-related issue.

Comment: If it's sorted on expiration time, you don't need a recurring timer.  Set the timer interval to that remaining before the expiration of the first item in the queue.  Any other timeouts before that are redundant.